# Hide/Remove items from lightning app menu

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

Is there any way to remove following items from Lightning App Menu

1. CMS Workspaces
2. Chatter
3. Discover Companies
4. Email Templates
5. Enhanced Letterheads
6. Home
7. News
8. Notes
9. Tasks

So far I had got links that confirm that

1. Approval Requests
2. Calendar
3. Lightning Bolt Solutions

cannot be hidden, but there is no such documentation for above 9 items.

Any help/pointers are appretiable.

Answer (score 0):

1. News tab can be controlled by disabling the news in account setting.
   follow this link:- [News](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=insights.htm&type=5)
2. Discover Companies cannot be removed as per this idea :- [Add ability to remove "Discover Companies" Tab](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003YoyQAE)
3. You can find limitation for chatter, task, Approval Requests here:- [Lightning Experience-Tab Limitations](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E7DXQA0). You do not have the ability to control these tab.